# anyone know how to detect numbers with ml kit in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I want to detect only numbers with ml kit in flutter. Texts are detecting fine but i want to get numbers searched Google many times but didn't get the answer i was looking for. can I set it to detect only numbers and not anything other than numbers?

anyone's any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there isnt a setting to limit to only numbers in text recognition yet in ml kit. But I assume you can do the recognition and filter out numbers?

Comment: Ml kit isn't recognising handwritten numbers well. This is the problem I'm facing